# SUM(value) as value SQL Query not working

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

so i have this functionin a clientPurchases class that selects the summation of value of a certain client on a certain month and year and returns it, if its empty returns 0.

my error is that the variable 'total' that display the total is returning with the wrong value

```
public function purchasesCount($month_id, $year_id)
    {    
        $purchasesCount = ClientPurchases::select(DB::raw('SUM(value) AS value'))
        ->where('client_id', $this->id)
        ->whereYear('date', '=', $year_id)
        ->whereMonth('date', '=', $month_id)
        ->get();

        if(!empty($purchasesCount->value)){
            return $purchasesCount->value;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

And then in my show.blade im trying to do a foreach to sum all the clients in a card whith this

```
<div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="carde card-1">
                    <h3>Clientes</h3>
                    <?php 
                        $total = 0;
                        foreach($clients as $client){
                           $valor = $client->purchasesCount($month, $year);
                           $total += $valor; 
                        }
                    ?>
                       
                    <h4 class="valor">{{ $total }} €</h4>
                    <h4 class="mes">{{date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $month - 1, 10))}}</h4>
                    <br>
                </div>
                </div>
```

im new to laravel so help would be grat tkx :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use [sum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#aggregates) method directly:

```
 $purchasesCount = ClientPurchases::
            where('client_id', $this->id)
            ->whereYear('date', '=', $year_id)
            ->whereMonth('date', '=', $month_id)
            ->sum('value');
return $purchasesCount;
```

Comment: and how to call the "sumed" alue on my blade? @OMR

Comment: It will only return you the value you just need to paste above code in the function and call the function in loop.